# ReactJS, Radium, AltJS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I just updated my project using NPM, and its unclear to me what is causing the following error. prefixer.js is from radium.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined - prefixer.js:173
>
> _getPrefixedValue @ prefixer.js:173(anonymous function) @
>   prefixer.js:275getPrefixedStyle @ prefixer.js:261resolveStyles @
>   resolve-styles.js:215(anonymous function) @
>   resolve-styles.js:154mapSingleChildIntoContext @
>   ReactChildren.js:97traverseAllChildrenImpl @
>   traverseAllChildren.js:111traverseAllChildrenImpl @
>   traverseAllChildren.js:133traverseAllChildren @
>   traverseAllChildren.js:246mapChildren @
>   ReactChildren.js:123resolveStyles @ resolve-styles.js:152render @
>   enhancer.js:34_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:789_renderValidatedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:816wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70mountComponent
>   @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:237wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:70mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38mountChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:192_createContentMarkup @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:289mountComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:199mountComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:38mountComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:247wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70mountComponent
>   @ ReactReconciler.js:38_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:764_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:726updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:642wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:70performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:539performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactReconciler.js:115runBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:151perform @
>   Transaction.js:134perform @ Transaction.js:134perform @
>   ReactUpdates.js:95flushBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:175wrapper @
>   ReactPerf.js:70closeAll @ Transaction.js:207perform @
>   Transaction.js:148batchedUpdates @
>   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:66enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdates.js:215enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:30enqueueSetState @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:208ReactComponent.setState @
>   ReactComponent.js:69onChange @ Player.js:61emit @
>   index.js:72AltStore.emitChange @ AltStore.js:54(anonymous function) @
>   AltStore.js:84Dispatcher.$Dispatcher_invokeCallback @
>   Dispatcher.js:220Dispatcher.dispatch @ Dispatcher.js:195(anonymous
>   function) @ index.js:74Alt.batchingFunction @ index.js:58dispatch @
>   index.js:73dispatch @ index.js:43setSource @
>   PlayerActions.js:6(anonymous function) @ Album.js:38(anonymous
>   function) @ Album.js:77fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @
>   jquery.js:3211done @ jquery.js:8264jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
>   @ jquery.js:8605

The line `this.setState(PlayerStore.getState())` seems to trigger this where my PlayerStore comes from Alt.

This is my Player.js file with the component that has the above line:

```
var React = require('react');
var Radium = require('radium');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Utils = require('../../utils/Utils');

/*** CONSTANTS ***/
var LayoutColors = require('../../constants/LayoutColors');
var LayoutSizes = require('../../constants/LayoutSizes');
var LayoutFonts = require('../../constants/LayoutFonts');

/*** COMPONENTS ***/
var PlayerSize = require('./PlayerSize');
var YouTube = require('../YouTube/YouTube');
var PlayerControlsTop = require('./PlayerControlsTop');
var PlayerControlsBottom = require('./PlayerControlsBottom');
var PlayerHeader = require('./PlayerHeader');
var PlayerSource = require('./PlayerSource');

/*** FLUX ***/
var PlayerStore = require('../../stores/PlayerStore');
var PlayerActions = require('../../actions/PlayerActions');

var Player = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {

    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {};
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return PlayerStore.getState();
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
//        PlayerActions.setSource(this.props.id, this.props.type, this.props.playingTrack);
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
/*
        if(nextProps.id != this.props.id
            || nextProps.type != this.props.type){

            PlayerActions.setSource(nextProps.id, nextProps.type, nextProps.playingTrack);                
        }
        else if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.playingTrack, this.state.playingTrack)){
            PlayerActions.setSource(nextProps.id, nextProps.type, nextProps.playingTrack);            
        }
*/
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        PlayerStore.listen(this.onChange);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {    
        //MAY COME BACK TO THIS... WILL NEVER NEED TO UNMOUNT
        //PlayerActions.unMount();    
        PlayerStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
    },
    onChange: function() {
        var toSet = PlayerStore.getState();   
        console.log('##### 1 #####');
        console.log(toSet);     
        this.setState(toSet);
    },

    /*** Youtube Events ***/
    onReady: function(event) {
        PlayerActions.setPlayer(event.target);
    },
    onDestroy: function() {
        console.log('onDestroy()');
//        PlayerActions.setPlayer(null);
    },  
    onProgressBarChange: function(current, total, perc) {
        PlayerActions.setProgressBar(current, total, perc);
    },
    onPlay: function() {
        PlayerActions.setPlaying(true);
    },
    onPause: function() {
        PlayerActions.setPlaying(false);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
        PlayerActions.forward();
    },

    /*** Render ***/

    render: function() {
        console.log('##### 2 #####');
        console.log(this.state);     


        var hover = Radium.getState(this.state, 'player', ':hover');

        var youtubeOptions = {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            playerVars: { // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
                start: this.state.start,
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                rel: 0,
                iv_load_policy: 3
            }
        };

        var youtubeElement = (this.state.playingTrack && this.state.playingTrack[this.state.mode]) ?
                                <YouTube 
                                    videoId={this.state.playingTrack[this.state.mode].youtubeId}
                                    opts={youtubeOptions}
                                    onReady={this.onReady}
                                    onDestroy={this.onDestroy}
                                    onPlay={this.onPlay}
                                    onPause={this.onPause}
                                    onProgressBarChange={this.onProgressBarChange}
                                    onEnd={this.onEnd} /> 

                                    : <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}></div>;

        if(this.state.source){
            var favoriteTrack = false;
            if(this.state.playingTrack){
                favoriteTrack = this.state.playingTrack.favorite;
            }

            var by = null;
            if(this.state.source.type == 'playlist'){
                by = this.state.source.owner;
            }
            else if(this.state.source.type == 'album'){
                by = this.state.source.artist;
            }

            return (
                <div key="player" style={containerStyle} >
                    <PlayerSize />
                    <div style={mainStyle}>
                        <PlayerControlsTop 
                            hover={hover}
                            playingTrack={this.state.playingTrack} />
                        <div style={youtubeStyle} >
                            {youtubeElement}
                        </div>
                        <PlayerControlsBottom 
                            hover={hover}
                            perc={this.state.perc}
                            current={this.state.current}
                            total={this.state.total}
                            playing={this.state.playing}
                            mute={this.state.mute}
                            random={this.state.random}
                            repeat={this.state.repeat} 
                            favoriteTrack={favoriteTrack} />
                    </div>
                    <PlayerHeader
                        title={this.state.source.title}
                        by={by}
                        type={Utils.capitalizeFirstLetter(this.state.source.type)}
                        hover={hover}
                        radio={this.state.radio} /> 
                    <PlayerSource 
                        type={this.state.source.type}
                        tracks={this.state.source.tracks}
                        favorite={this.state.favorite}
                        playingTrack={this.state.playingTrack}
                        mode={this.state.mode}
                        hover={hover} />
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                <div style={containerStyle}></div>
            );
        }

    }
});

/*** STYLES ***/

var containerStyle = {
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: 2,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    top: LayoutSizes.topHeight,
    backgroundColor: LayoutColors.darkGrey,
    color: LayoutColors.darkGreyText,
    width: LayoutSizes.rightWidth,
    borderLeft: '1px solid '+LayoutColors.black,

    ':hover': {}
};

var mainStyle = {
    backgroundColor: LayoutColors.black
};

var youtubeStyle = {
    height: LayoutSizes.playerHeightSmall,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 2
};

module.exports = Radium(Player);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time prefixer calls `toString` is on the [value of a property when it is not a string](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/blob/6438547c1073f5a71ab84395099e39e35903c933/modules/prefixer.js#L187). So if you are seeing this error, you must be passing null or undefined as the value for some property. Radium should probably just warn you about this and ignore it.

We'll track this [over on GitHub](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/245).